# How to Cut a String in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have the phrases:

- "Shiloh Match Jolie",
- "Zahara Marley Novel",
- "Pax Dix Bat",
- "Maddox Chivan Jcalie"

I want to get all last character in phrases:

> "Jolie","Novel","Bat","Jcalie" in `angularJs`.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try split using space as pattern per each item and getting the last element of each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `split()` and `parts[parts.length - 1]` to get the last name.

Refer the below code reference

```js
const names = [
  "Shiloh Match Jolie",
  "Zahara Marley Novel",
  "Pax Dix Bat",
  "Maddox Chivan Jcalie"
];

// Function to extract last names
function getLastNames(names) {
  return names.map(fullName => {
    const parts = fullName.split(' ');
    return parts[parts.length - 1];
  });
}

const lastNames = getLastNames(names);
console.log(lastNames);
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have added an additional function that returns the last word of the `phrase`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.phrases = ["Shiloh Match Jolie", "Zahara Marley Novel", "Pax Dix Bat", "Maddox Chivan Jcalie"];
     
        // Returns the last word of a phrase
        $scope.getLastWord = function (phrase) {
            var words = phrase.trim().split(' ');
            return words[words.length - 1];
        };
        
        // Returns the last character of a phrase
        $scope.getLastCharacter = function (phrase) {
            // Assuming the phrase is not empty
            return phrase.trim().slice(-1);
        };
    });
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phrase in phrases">
              Last Word in the Pharse : {{ getLastWord(phrase) }}
              Last Character in the Last Word of the Pharse: {{ getLastCharacter(phrase) }},
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```